# Saving a large color image as `GTiff` with `gdal`

Tags: python, image, numpy, gis, gdal

I'm trying to save a large image of size `(15000, 80000, 3)`. This array is a numpy array that I initialized as `im_final = np.zeros((15000,80000,,3))`. To do the saving, I use `gdal` like so:

```
dst_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create('val.tif', 80000, 15000, 3, gdal.GDT_Byte)
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(im_final[:,:,0])   # write r-band to the    raster
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(im_final[:,:,1])   # write g-band to the raster
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(3).WriteArray(im_final[:,:,2])   # write b-band to the raster
dst_ds.FlushCache()                     # write to disk
dst_ds = None
```

When I save it, the resulting image is black and white. However, I need the image to be RGB, does anyone know what the issue is? Furthermore, the values in `im_final` are `uint16`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to write `uint16` into a `uint8` (`gdal.GDT_Byte`) image. If you really need a 8-bit image (such as if you want to view this image in non-GIS programs), the best practice is to scale `im_final` to between 0-255. This could be a mapping from 0-65535 to 0-255 or min/max of each band to 0-255 or any other number of ways.

If the values in `im_final` are important then use `gdal.GDT_UInt16` in `driver.Create()`.

Comment: Ah, can I only view the `uint16` output in a GIS program? I tried viewing the output on my mac and I get this error: `It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize`.

Comment: There are many programs that can handle 16-bit images (Adobe Photoshop, other image-manipulation software, GIS). If you want to publish the image to the web, for instance, then 8-bit RGB (jpeg or png) is probably your best bet.