# convert a Pandas dataframe to geotiff image

Tags: python

I have classified the data in pandas dataframe and i want to convert the dataframe into geotiff image with the resolution of 250 m. In my dataframe, each latlong represents centroid of 250 m grid. It has two columns includes Latlong `['74.70912526938625', '14.52405907246895']` and class value "2". How to convert it into raster data in python.

I tried by converting into shapefile and into gtiff but it doesn't work.

Comment: did you research about this in google?

Comment: what was the solution?

Comment: Sorry couldn't find a solution

Comment: did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537599